# Correct order of socket calls for pre-fork server

Tags: linux, sockets, posix

What happens if I do (pseudo-code below):

```
s = socket
bind s 
fork .... 
   (... at child ...)
   listen s 
   conn = accept s
```

? Should I use instead:

```
s = socket 
bind s 
listen s 
fork .... 
   conn = accept s
```

?

Which one is correct? Also, do I need to set any options on the socket for this particular scenario?

Comment: Actually neither is correct http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_sockets/socket_server_example.htm look at last example.

Comment: @RomainHippeau Thanks. That second example is not pre-fork as I understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Which one is correct [, calling `listen()` before or after `fork()`]?*

Calling `listen()` *before* the `fork()` is correct.  The effect of `listen()` is to mark the underlying socket as ready for connections with a connection backlog.  It need only be called once.

I'd label the other approach "incorrect" from the perspective of code quality, in that it's redundant and confusing.

While it's not harmful to call `listen()` repeatedly, it's quite dubious.  The specification does not say what happens when a subsequent call is made, merely that a connection-oriented socket shall [*"maintain a queue of outstanding connection indications"*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_10_13), that is, a backlog of pending connections.  Would a subsequent call be able to change the size of the backlog?  Would you want it to?  Indeed, not all operating systems even let you query the size of the backlog (FreeBSD has, e.g., [SO_LISTENQLIMIT](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=setsockopt&sektion=2#DESCRIPTION)).

Answer (score 1):

On Linux (since 3.9) (and [Mac OS](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/setsockopt.2.html) and [FreeBSD](https://mebsd.com/man?program=setsockopt&section=) and possibly others), you also have the option of using `SO_REUSEPORT`.

```c
// _DEFAULT_SOURCE for htobe16 for the port number, you may need _BSD_SOURCE instead
#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <endian.h>

int main() {
    struct sockaddr_in6 sa;
    int v = 1;

    // prepare ipv6 address [::]:1345 
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sa.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    sa.sin6_port = htobe16(1345);

    int s = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    perror("socket");

    // the key point: enable SO_REUSEPORT
    setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &v, sizeof(v));
    perror("setsockopt");

    // from this point on just plain old socket use
    bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&sa, sizeof(sa));
    perror("bind");
    listen(s, 0);
    perror("listen");

    while (1) {
        int conn = accept(s, NULL, NULL);
        perror("accept");
        close(conn);
        perror("close");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that no parent/child relationship is required between the processes. Also, the manpage (`setsockopt(7)`) suggests that this has performance improvements over traditional approaches.

In this scenario, you can fork *before* the call to `socket`. The only requirement is that *all* involved processes set `SO_REUSEPORT` on their socket and share the same effective UID.

Comment: This is super cool!  It probably won't work in Mac OS X,  so I won't feel too bad about the day of refactoring to enable pre-fork, but I'll definitely look for ways of using this in Linux.

Comment: Make sure to check. SO_REUSEPORT was a bigger thing when it landed, I can imagine that BSDs and Mac OS have also implemented this.

Comment: See the edit, I found an apple manpage suggesting that SO_REUSEPORT is available.

Comment: Thanks, my pre-fork doesn't work very well with the epoll event manager of Haskell, so I will have to resort to on of these ;-) Good to know that it is in Mac!